# Redirecting web traffic in a server hosting both an Apache and a Glassfish web

Tags: apache, glassfish

I am hosting two web pages in my server. One is running on Apache and the another one on Glassfish. By now I solve the redirection problem making the Glassfish server to listen on a port distinct than the 80. The problem is that I think my web users have a firewall blocking those ports so they can´t access the GlassFish web. Which way would you recommend me to take in order to make a URL request-based redirection? **I want to make the glassfish web a subdomain of the Apache one, being both running at the same IP.**

If I have not been sufficiently clear with my question, please let me know

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried modifying the domain or using subdomains? If one application is eg. at http://subdomain1.yourdomain.net and another at http://subdomain2.yourdomain.net it should do the trick without any problems. Or try http://yourdomain.net for your main program and http://yourdomain.net/somecontext for sub program. That looks meaningful also for the service user.

Tick the answer if you got help :)